# How to reuse a static GeometryDrawing in a DrawingImage using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

If I define in app.xaml a GeometryDrawing like this:

```
<GeometryDrawing x:Key="ReuseThis" 
    Pen="..." 
    Brush="..." 
    Geometry="..."/>
```

How can I then use it later in a DrawingImage like this:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="FullImage">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing reuse it here somehow"{StaticResource ReuseThis}"/>
            <Geometrydrawing ...>
            <Geometrydrawing ...>
           </DrawingGroup>
      </DrawingImage.Drawing>
 </DrawingImage>
```

I'm trying to avoid copying and pasting that GeometryDrawing in a bunch of DrawingImages I have.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [StaticResource Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension) in XAML Object Element Syntax:

```
<DrawingImage>
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="ReuseThis"/>
            <GeometryDrawing .../>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```